# pandas read_sql to return last row's date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas to read_sql table and return only the last date to me.

```
pandas.read_sql('sqltable', con=engine)['Date'].tail(1)
```

**this returns**

```
#Index # Date
2589   2016-03-07
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But If I do this:

```
pandas.read_sql('sqltable', con=engine)['Date'].ix[0]
```

**it returns**

```
# Starting Date     # Time stamp
2012-08-23          00:00:00
```

How can I just get it to show me `2016-03-07` and nothing else? I tried combining `.tail(1).ix[0]` together but it gives me an error instead.

How should I do this?

Comment: `pandas.read_sql('sqltable', con=engine).tail(1)['Date']`?

Comment: @N.Wouda Nope.. This gives me the `index` and the `Date` along with the `dtype` etc..

Comment: Sorry, add `.values`, that should return only the date.

Comment: This now returns me `2016-03-07T08:00:00.000000000+0800` Is it not possible to just get `2016-03-07`

Comment: That is your date, but you may want to consider formatting it differently.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but how should I be doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I used `pandas.DatetimeIndex` to solve my problem.

```
ddd = pandas.read_sql('sqltable', con=engine)['Date'].tail(1).values
fff = pandas.DatetimeIndex(ddd).date[0]
print(fff)
```

output

```
2016-03-07
```

Comment: but this would force a query of the entire table